# Is the accept rate still shown anywhere?

Tags: support

I read [Let's stop displaying a user's accept rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) and I'm wondering if we can still see our accept rate or not? If yes how?

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you link says *"Starting with the next build accept rate will no longer be shown."*....seems to answer it just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is no longer shown to users. It is still calculated in the back end though, like flag weight.

It was removed from display in [January 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161595/187954).

Comment: what is the use of calculating in back end, if it is not showing either ???

Comment: They may opt to bring it back someday. Or find a use for it. Flag weight is used to semi determine how many flags you get, even though it's not shown any more. However, I don't think accept rate is used for something similar.

Comment: @PradipKharbuja It's exposed via our [API](http://api.stackexchange.com), so removing it completely would be a breaking change.